# Find $(a^2+b^2),$ where $(a+b)=\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{a}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers

The question is the same .Find $a^2+b^2$. I think we have to find $a$ and $b$ firstly. Given that $a$ and $b$ are integers.

Comment: Please keep question self contained and not a continuation of the title (that does not mean don't keep the title descriptive). There is some formula error too.

Comment: Where did $c$ come from?

Comment: What is $c$? Isn't it should be $a$? If it is so then $a^2+b^2=ab(a+b)$.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your formula is $a+b=\dfrac ab+\dfrac ba,$ then $a^2+b^2=ab(a+b)$ and since $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab,$ we have $$x^2-2y=xy,$$ where $x=a+b$ and $y=ab.$ From here you can find $x$ in-terms of $y$ as $$x=\dfrac{y\pm\sqrt{y^2+8y}}{2}.$$ Then $$\color{Green}{a^2+b^2=\left(\dfrac{y\pm\sqrt{y^2+8y}}{2}\right)y},$$ where $y$ is a parameter.

> Also, if you only interest on $a,b$ integer solutions, we need to find $y$ so that $y^2+8y$ is a perfect square.

Edit:
To do this, note that $z^2=y^2+8y=(y+4)^2-16$ implies $16=(y-z+4)(y+z+4).$ Now find the all possible values of $y-z+4$ and $y+z+4$ using factors of $16.$ Then you will have to solve few simultaneous equations to find corresponding $y.$

Later:

> As @MANMAID pointed out $y=1$ is the only possible value and this gives us $$\color{Red}{a^2+b^2=2.}$$

Comment: you must show there exist perfect squares of the form $y^2+8y$ other than $y=1$...

Comment: Obviously $y=0$ is another one and it is not difficult to find all such $y$ values by considering the equation $y(y+8)=z^2.$

Comment: if "it is not difficult to find", then give some example, sir. This is **not an answer** until you do so... OP strictly used $a,b$ are integers (btw $y=0$ is not a solution, check that!)

Comment: $(y+4)^2=z^2+4^2$, then $(4,z,y+4)$ is a pythagorean triple.

Comment: Yes of course. I edit my answer and add details but not computation.

Comment: I guess you are missing the point that only pythagorean triple that contains $4$ is $(4,3,5)$, check that too...

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice it. Nice. It makes this way better (Then $y=1$ is the only solution, which gives $a^2+b^2=2$).

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 3):

**Lemma(1)**: Let $a$ & $b$ to be integers such that $ab \mid a^2+b^2$. 
If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then prove that $a=\pm b$.

Proof: We claim that $ab=\pm 1$.

- Proof of the **claim**: Suppose on contrary; that $1 < |ab|$. 
  So there exist a prime number $p$, which divides $ab$; i.e. $p \mid ab$. 
  Without loss of generality we can assume that $p \mid a$. 
  So $p$ must divides $b^2=(a^2+b^2)-a^2$. 
  [Because $p$ divides both of the $(a^2+b^2)$ & $a^2$.] 
  So we can conclude that $p$ must divides $b$; 
  which is an obvious contradiction with the assumption that $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

So we can conclude that $a=\pm 1$ & $b=\pm 1$; which implies that $a=\pm b$.

---

---

**Lemma(2)**: Let $a$ & $b$ to be integers such that $ab \mid a^2+b^2$. 
Prove that $a=\pm b$.

Proof: Let $d:=\gcd(a,b)$, 
so there exist integers $a^{\prime}$ & $b^{\prime}$ such that:

$$ 
a=da^{\prime} \ , \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
b=db^{\prime} \ , \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\gcd(a^{\prime},b^{\prime})=1 . $$

The relation $ab \mid a^2+b^2$, implies that there is an integer $k$, 
such that:

$$
k(ab) = a^2+b^2  
\Longrightarrow 
k\big( (da^{\prime})(db^{\prime}) \big) = (da^{\prime})^2+(db^{\prime})^2 
\Longrightarrow 
k\big( a^{\prime}b^{\prime} \big) = (a^{\prime})^2+(b^{\prime})^2 , 
$$

so we obtain a pair $(a^{\prime},b^{\prime})$ such that:

$$a^{\prime}b^{\prime} \mid (a^{\prime})^2+(b^{\prime})^2 \ , 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\gcd(a^{\prime},b^{\prime})=1 .$$

So by **Lemma(1)** we have:

$$a=d(a^{\prime})=d(\pm b^{\prime})=\pm d(b^{\prime})=\pm b .$$

---

---

The relation

$$a+b=\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a} \ \ , \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)  $$

implies $ab(a+b)=a^2+b^2$, 
so we have: $ab \mid a^2+b^2$, 
so by the **Lemma(2)** we have one of the two folowing cases:

- $a= + b$ , in this case both of the fractions 
  on the Right-hand-side of the relation $(*)$, 
  both are equal to $+1$, 
  so the R-H-S is equal to $+ 2$. 
  On the other hand in this case the Left-hand-side of the relation $(*)$ is equal to $2a$, so must have: $2a=+2$, which yields the solution $a=b=+1$.
- $a= - b$ , in this case both of the fractions 
  on the Right-hand-side of the relation $(*)$, 
  both are equal to $-1$, 
  so the R-H-S is equal to $- 2$. 
  On the other hand in this case the Left-hand-side of the relation $(*)$ is equal to $0$, so must have: $0=-2$, which is impossible.

So the quantity $a^2+b^2$ will be equal to $2$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $|a|= a'd$, $\>|b|= b'd$ with $d\geq1$ and ${\rm gcd}(a',b')=1$. Then
$$a+b={a\over b}+{b\over a}=\pm\left({a'\over b'}+{b'\over a'}\right)$$
is integer only if both fractions on the right hand side are integers, and this is only the case if $a'=b'=1$. It follows that $|a|=|b|$ and $a+b=\pm2$, hence $a=b=\pm1$ and $a^2+b^2=2$.

Answer (score 2):

The condition gives $$(a+b)ab=a^2+b^2$$ or
$$(b-1)a^2+b^2a-b^2=0.$$

If $b=1$ we obtain $a=1$ and $a^2+b^2=2$.

If $b\neq1$ we need $b^4+4b^2(b-1)=m^2$, where $m\in\mathbb N$ or
$$b^2+4b-4=n^2,$$
where $n\in\mathbb N$ or
$$(b+2)^2=8+n^2$$ or
$$(n-b-2)(n+b+2)=-8$$ and since $n>0$, we obtain two cases only:

1. $n-b-2=4$ and $n+b+2=-2$, which gives $n=1$, $b=-5$, $a=\frac{5}{2}$ or $a=\frac{5}{3},$ which is impossible;
2. $n-b-2=-2$ and $n+b+2=4$, which gives $n=1$, $b=1,$ which is impossible here.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

$$a+b=\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}$$

therefore,$$a^2+b^2=ab(a+b)$$
or,$$a^2(1-b)+b^2(1-a)=0$$
from this relation we can say $1-b=1-a=0$

therefore,$$a=b=1$$

so finally,
$$a^2+b^2=2$$

Comment: $ax^2+by^2=0$ does not implies $a=b=0.$

Comment: The Question specifies that $a,b$ are integers.  Possibly you can use this assumption to fix the above gap in your solution.