# Two positive integers $a$ and $b$ are such that $a+b=\frac{a}{b} +\frac{b}{a}$ . What is the value of $a^2 + b^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Two positive integers $a$ and $b$ are such that $a+b=\frac{a}{b} +\frac{b}{a}$ . What is the value of $a^2 + b^2$?

Got this in a sample question paper for a contest but i have no idea how to solve it. I tried to apply inequalities but it did it not work. Please help

Comment: $$a+b = \frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}\Longrightarrow a^2+b^2 = ? $$

Comment: Duplicate of   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381988/find-a2b2-where-ab-dfracab-dfracba/2382390#2382390

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hints:
$$\frac{a}{b} \le a$$
$$\frac{b}{a} \le b$$
If either inequality is strict, you get an immediate contradiction.

If both inequalities are equalities, then . . .

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem and elegant solution of @quasi.

Alternatively: Without loss of generality, assume $1\le a\le b$. Then:
$$a+b=\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\le \frac{b}{b}+\frac{b}{1}=1+b\Rightarrow a\le 1 \Rightarrow a=1.$$